# Retrieve phone number from a signed in user profile from google plus login in android

Tags: android, phone-number, user-profile, google-plus-signin

I need to retrieve phone number from a signed in user profile from google plus after login in android. Currently by referring to https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_profile_information_for_a_signed_in_user. I got basic profile information. But what  actually require is phone number. Is it possible / are they providing any way.

Comment: google plus API does not provide any way to get user's contact number, even if they have made it public

Answer (score 1):

I dont think, currently there is option for fetching phone number . You can go through Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson.