# How to get full profile from integrate google plus in my app?

Tags: android, google-plus-signin

Hi I am trying sing in google plus in my app and after login get user full profile birthday ,firstName, lastname,gender,contact number ,etc

```
private void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personID = currentPerson.getId();
            String AgeRange  = String.valueOf(currentPerson.getAgeRange());


            String Place = String.valueOf(currentPerson.getPlacesLived());
            String personNamef = String.valueOf(currentPerson.getName()); //Gives First Name and Last Name in Json formay
            int personGender = currentPerson.getGender(); //Gives Gender in int 0:Male, 1:Female
            String personCircle = String.valueOf(currentPerson.getCircledByCount());
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
            if(personGender == 0){
                gen = "Male";
            }
            if(personGender == 1){
                gen = "Female";
            }
            if(personGender == 2){
                gen = "Other";
            }


            Log.e(TAG, "First Name: " + personNamef + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", ID: " + personID
                    + ", AgeRange: " + AgeRange +
                     ", CircledByCount: " + personCircle +

                    ", PlacesLived: " + Place);

            txtName.setText(personName);
            txtEmail.setText(email);
            txtGender.setText(gen);


            // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
            // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
            // replacing sz=X
            personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                    personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                    + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

            new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I do not get full profile here please help me .. Thanks in Advance

Comment: may be they didn't registered name or date of birth in their profiles.

Comment: this is not problem @shadow

Comment: then what's the problem? any log error or you can't display any name/email?

Comment: @shadow name,email,profile pic ,gender are display but birthday, Current location,contact number are not display

Answer (score 1):

Google plus API does not provide any way to get user's contact number, even if they have made it public!!
For more details Visit [Retrieve phone number from a signed in user profile from google plus login in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871748/retrieve-phone-number-from-a-signed-in-user-profile-from-google-plus-login-in-an?rq=1)